# Bower permission denied

Tags: angularjs, bower-install

I am using the following angular-seed app: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

And when I execute `$ bower install` I receive the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                    throw err;
                    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/Mac/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
at readCachedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
at defaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
```

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: have you looked at the permissions of that file?  Maybe since it was generated it didn't get the correct permissions

Comment: Did you tried using "sudo bower install" ?  If after this also its not working you may have to change the user and group for .config location on your system. Refer: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2262. Its says to use  these commands: "sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm"
  and "sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config"

Comment: @LukeP.Issac, I did try `sudo bower install` and that was not successful. Neither was changing the permissions. I will look into the user and group .cong file.

Comment: @DaveV, the file path doesn't exist: `/Users/Mac/.config/configstore/bower-github.json`. I did try a chmod in the home directory and within the project folder itself and that didn't work either.

Comment: Does the path exist and the file just isn't in it or does the path not even exist?

Comment: @DaveV, the path does not exist

Comment: Important to note, that bower is installed globally. I receive the following message after `$ npm install -g bower`. Response: `/usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/usr/local/lib
└── bower@1.7.9`

Comment: Update: I unhide the files on my Mac and I have found the folder, and the file it says I don't have permission to. I opened it and nothing is in it....what is the error message asking me to do?

Comment: thank you @DaveV and @Luke P. Issac  for responding. I posted the same question on different platforms and received an answer that worked. So @Luke P. Issac your answer was correct! I was just missing the `$ bower init`. Full answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I asked multiple people on different channels and got a solution to the problem. Figured I would post it here just in case someone had the same issues as me. I did the following commands

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
```

then

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

then

```
$ bower init
```

completed the answers and then did

```
$ bower install
```